# WPF Image source binding is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, linq-to-twitter

I have a WPF application which used `LinqToTwitter` as data source for a `ListBox`. The data that is rendered inside the `DataTemplate` comes from the twitter source which has a text and image.

`SocialFeedView.xaml` code

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="#1da1f2">
        <TextBlock Text="#BluesAllDay" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  FontSize="20" FontWeight="DemiBold" 
                   Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DockPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox x:Name="TweetList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Tweets}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="UniformToFill"
                               Margin="3" Width="50" Height="50" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="17"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox></StackPanel>
```

This is the underlying code for its view model

```
private ObservableCollection<Tweet> _tweets;
    public ObservableCollection<Tweet> Tweets
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tweets == null)
            {
                _tweets = new ObservableCollection<Tweet>();
            }
            return _tweets;
        }
        set { Set(ref _tweets, value, x => x.Tweets); }
    }

    private SingleUserAuthorizer authorizer = new SingleUserAuthorizer
    {
        CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
        {
            ConsumerKey = "xxxxxxxx",
            ConsumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            AccessToken = "xxxxxxxxxx",
            AccessTokenSecret = "xxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    };

    private List<Status> currentTweets;

    public SocialFeedViewModel()
    {
        GetMostRecent200HomeTimeLine();

        if (Tweets != null) Tweets.Clear();
        currentTweets.ForEach(tweet => Tweets.Add(new Tweet { Text = tweet.Text, Image = new System.Uri(tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl, UriKind.Absolute) }));
    }

    private void GetMostRecent200HomeTimeLine()
    {
        var twitterContext = new TwitterContext(authorizer);

        var tweets = from tweet in twitterContext.Status
                     where tweet.Type == StatusType.Home && tweet.Count == 200
                     select tweet;

        if (currentTweets != null) currentTweets.Clear();

        currentTweets = tweets.ToList();
    }

    public void PullNew200HomeTimeLine()
    {
        GetMostRecent200HomeTimeLine();

        if (Tweets != null) Tweets.Clear();
        currentTweets.ForEach(tweet => Tweets.Add(new Tweet { Text = tweet.Text, Image = new System.Uri(tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl, UriKind.Absolute) }));
    }
}

public class Tweet
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Uri Image { get; set; }
}
```

The binding mechanism of `ObservableCollection` of type Tweet is working though.  But, one problem is that the `<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>` component doesn't show the image from the Tweet. Image class which is of type URI.

I'm stuck on this, and have run out of options on how to make it work.

This is the `ListBox` output (the red box should show the `ProfileImageUrl` retrieved from the Tweets collection)

[image]

Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provided that `tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl` contains a valid URL, your code should work. You may omit `UriKind.Absolute` from the Uri constructor call.

Comment: @Clemens, I have omitted `UriKind.Absolute` but still the image is not rendered.  I checked the Tweets collection, [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1S0vrR6A9T8YW1QNVB1eFEtdDA) and seems the Image has the correct Uri structure.  I also did this `<Image Source="{Binding Image.AbsoluteUri}" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="3" Width="50" Height="50" />`, but no image appears.  Do you have an idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Does the image show in your web browser when you paste the URL there?

Comment: @Clemens, yes it does.  It's strange why the image doesn't show up.  This is one of the image item inside the Tweet collection, please click this [link](http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/689204218138263552/mfOFwIxk_normal.jpg)

Comment: @Prajwal, did you omit your answer?  Yesterday, you have provided an answer.  But, it's not in this page anymore.

Comment: And does it in a simple WPF app with a single Image, like `<Image Source="<your image url>" />`? User Prajwal has deleted his answer because what he suggested wouldn't work.

Comment: @Clemens, please check this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1S0vrR6A9T8YW1QNVB1eFEtdDA) and open ImageSource.png  That could be the problem why the image is not rendered?

Comment: Obviously, yes.

Comment: @Clemens, did you encountered this before?

Comment: No, I've never tried to access any twitter profile image. You should search the web for "get twitter profile image" or something alike to get more info.